# How to get row if value from one dataframe is in another?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

```
df1 = {'Stream': ['Netflix', 'Hulu', 'YouTube', 'Aprime', 'HBO', 'Peacock', 'Tubi'],
       'Percent': [51, 19, 40, 18, 35, 12, 7]}
df2 = {'Test': ['Hulu', 'Netflix', 'Disney']}
```

I want to see if they're any instances of `df2` in `df1`. If there are, I then want to print the `df1` row. The result I'm looking for:

```
Stream  Percent
Hulu    19
Netflix 51
```

I was thinking of something like below, but I can't figure it out:

```
for row in df1:
    if row['Stream'] == df2['Test']:
       print(row)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `isin`

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
df1[df1["Stream"].isin(df2.Test)]

Out[523]: 
    Stream  Percent
0  Netflix       51
1     Hulu       19
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this would be to use `inner` join on the 2 DataFrames. More details [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html). -

```
df2.set_index('Test').join(df1.set_index('Stream'), how='inner')
```

```
         Percent
Hulu          19
Netflix       51
```